# Open specific Tab when link is clicked from another page

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

Good day guys, I need help,

When a link is clicked on another page I need the tab to be displayed after the page loads, I've seen this being done using the hash #id but is there any possible way to do this with the data-filter as they're the ones controlling the tabs?

```
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="filters">
            <li class="active"><a href="#" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".Tab1">Tab1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".Tab2">Tab2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-filter=".Tab3">Tab3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can give css display:none; after that use jquery window on load event then make it display:initial; and you're done...

Comment: for better answer what version of bootstrap do you use?

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap v3.3.0

Comment: You need to pass special request parameter from source page, for example `/my-page?tab=tab-name`. Then it is possible to use document [ready handler](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) to get the parameter value and activate corresponding tab.

Comment: I'm not really skilled in Javascript @Alexander would you be able to help me out with the code on how to get this done?

Answer (score 2):

You could pass special request parameter in query string. Then get the parameter value and activate corresponding tab.

For example, add `tab-name` into query string of target URL (the full relative URL is `/my-page?tab-name=profile`). Following expression returns value of the parameter, that equals to `'profile'`:

```
var tabName = (window.location.href.match(/[?&]tab-name=[^&$]+/i) || '=').split('=')[1];
```

If `tab-name` is omitted the expression returns empty string.

Then select navigation tab by received value and activate its associated pane using [`show`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabshow) method.

```js
var tabName = (window.location.href.match(/[?&]tab-name=[^&$]+/i) || '=').split('=')[1];
tabName='profile'; // remove this line on real page
if(tabName.length)
  $('#myTabs .nav-link[href="#' + tabName + '"]').tab('show');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="myTabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="messages-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="settings-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

Note, in the snippet I set value of `tabName` directly, because it is not possible to send custom request to the snippet. So, you have to remove `tabName='profile';` on your real page.

Comment: Hey thanks, this should work perfect for tabs that are setup to use id's to function instead of the data filter, think I should change my tab setup and use this method